# Assignment of ternary operator to different variables in C#

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

If there are these variables:

```
bool _v;
int c = 5;
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
```

Is it possible to express

```
if (_v)
{
   a+=c;
}
else
{
  b+=c;
}
```

using a ternary operator?

Comment: Not directly. A ternary is an _expression_, and as such, resolves to a single value. You can't update 2 variables.

Comment: Even if you *can*, doing so is a terrible idea. Unclear to read, hard to debug, ...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - That's not quite the same thing (though it shows the structure for it). I think it would be `(a,b) = _v ? (a + c, b) : (a, b + c);` But....ewww.... :-) What is that feature called in C#?

Comment: Just because you *can* do something... ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
(_v ? ref a : ref b) += c;
```

Comment: That's false, it works: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmABgFgAoaolAAgDEIIAKYFgG3oH0A3AJTUA3tXrj6ASzwZ6YegF56AVgDcYidNkBDRfTLqqEqTPrA9BjeKv1W/egH56sAGb1dIZzDfAB9ANRKYIYAvtTUzGwYuDAChpGsLtqcAM6xqkA

Comment: If you're wondering what language rule permits it, it's explicitly special cased as one of allowed ternary operator forms, with semantics to support this exact scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1218-conditional-operator

Comment: Ooo, perfectly unreadable code! It's a great time to be a maintenance programmer. Please don't turn modern C# into modern C++

Comment: would that be a better way to code this condition?

Comment: ok, it works, both with assignment and increments!